# how do I show the parameters of a report in a textbox on the report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I have a date range as parameters on my report, @dt_begin and @dt_end.
On the header of the report I would like to display "report run from @dt_begin to @dt_end".
with the actual date values in it, example:

"Report run from 14-Oct-2013 to 16-Oct-2013".

How can I do that?
thanks and regards
Marcelo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In expressions, refer to parameter values using `Parameters!param.Value`.

In your example, add an expression similar to this to a textbox in the header:

```
="Report run from " & Format(Parameters!dt_begin.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
  & " to "
  & Format(Parameters!dt_end.Value, "dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

All it's doing is formatting your parameters and adding them to a larger string.

Comment: You're welcome! If an answer solves your issue, please consider setting it as accepted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work